# Webpack plugin: difference between webpack-contrib/closure-webpack-plugin and google/closure-compiler-js?

Tags: webpack, google-closure-compiler

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-js provides a Webpack interface, so why is the Webpack team building their own plugin?

Comment: The webpack team didn't build it - I did. The java version didn't have a webpack option.

Comment: Chad do you want to promote this to an answer?

Comment: I'm not linking the Java version, but "closure-compiler-js" which does have a Webpack interface: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-js#webpack. I guess now I'm even more confused.